# colorbox - inline html not showing

Tags: html, colorbox

Essentially, I want to make a colorbox pop up upon clicking the link "About Us" as seen on "Inline HTML" under Other Content Types at [Inline HTML example](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/). However, the link doesn't do anything. I have also double checked the files in the header and they do link to the right directory.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../Colorbox/example1/colorbox.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="copyright" class="container">
<p>&copy; All rights reserved. | <a class='inline' href="#inline_content">About Us</a> | <a class ="contact">Contact Us</a></p>

</div>
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
<p><strong>This is a test.</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors like '$(...).colorbox is not a function' in the browser console ?

Comment: What's the console saying? It's hard to say from your code alone. Have you definitely linked the libraries correctly?

Comment: Well, damn it. Totally forgot about the console. This really helped me. Turns out there were linkage errors (read permissions in the server)! Thanks limekin and Jay.